# " ' " (Single Quote) got converted to &#39; How do I replace it or fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I sent a Dictionary to Django Template, Its " ' " got converted to ' How do I convert or Replace it?

I have tried using replace function, It doesn't work.

```
Dictionary_passed = {"-" : "100", "GERMANY" : "1500"}

In the HTML template I got
{&#39;-&#39;:&#39;100&#39;,&#39;GERMANY&#39:&#39;1500&#39; }

on Dictionary_passed.replace('&#39;', ''), I get:
{&#39l-&#39;:100, 'GERMANY&#39;:1500}


**__all_users is query set returned by auth_User, userprofile is just another table that extends auth_user**

countries_list = dict(collections.Counter(map(lambda z : z.upper().strip(), 100*list(__all_users.values_list('userprofile__country', flat=True)))))

I have passed countries_list to the Django Template
```

Comment: How are you trying to render the dictionary in the template? Show us your view code (where you are passing the template context) and the template code.

Comment: show your view and template

Comment: I want to use that dictionary directly in the template, It is being passed to some api function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only had to mark it as safe text before sending it to the template.

One can check it here [mark safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.html)

Thanks